# How to check if there is a connection coming in on the server using Python Socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, python-sockets

So I am trying to combine Tkinter and Socket together to make an application.
Everything was going fine and well until I wanted to accept the connection.
Basically, if I try to accept a connection on the server that is not even there, it stops the program's mainloop. So what I want to do is accept the connection *only* when there is a connection coming through. How is this possible?

This is basically what I want to achieve:

```
if there is a connection:
   accept it
else:
   wait for a connection
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Comment: `select` allows to wait for a connection to be available with either a timeout or an immediate return.

Comment: Better use a child thread to wait for connection.